# Spritekit - Tableview scrolling cut off

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, sprite-kit

I’m currently developing a Menu screen in my sprite kit game to show all of the items and i’ve used a tableview to achieve this because it allows me to have a uilabel for the item description.
my uitableview is subclassed as follows:

**UITableview Class**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameRoomTableView: UITableView,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var items: [String] = []
var descrip: [String] = []
var title: [String] = []

var isFirstViewAlreadyAdded = false
var isSecondViewAlreadyAdded = false

override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self
    coreDataItemRetrieveval()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return items.count
}

func coreDataItemRetrieveval() {

    items.removeAll(); descrip.removeAll(); title.removeAll()

    items.append("Player1")
    descrip.append("Grown on Astrums Home world of Zaharia the forbidden fruit when eaten results in a headstart for the player")
    title.append("Athia Fruit")

    items.append("Player2")
    descrip.append("HHHHHH HHHHHH HHHHHHHHHH HHHHHHH HHHHHHHH HHHHHHHH HHHHHHHHH HHHHHHHHH ")
    title.append("AtTTTTTTT")

    items.append("Player2")
    descrip.append("TESTING ")
    title.append("AtTTTTTTT")

    items.append("Player2")
    descrip.append("TESTING ")
    title.append("AtTTTTTTT")

    items.append("Player2")
    descrip.append("TESTING ")
    title.append("AtTTTTTTT")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.backgroundView = nil

    return 1 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellIdentifier: String = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier)

        if cell == nil {

            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

            //IMPLEMENT CORE DATA RETRIEVEAL AND SO ON TO MAKE IT BETTER USE APPEND ARRAYS AND SO ON TO GET THIS DONE AND IMPLEMENT QUANTITY LABEL.

            cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:(self.items[indexPath.section] + ".png"))
            cell?.imageView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5);

            cell?.textLabel?.text = self.descrip[indexPath.section]
            cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell?.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            cell?.textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.size.width)! / 2.6, y: (cell?.frame.size.height)! / 1.7, width: 150, height: 50)

            let textlabel2 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.size.width)! / 2.6, y: (cell?.frame.size.height)! / 1.4, width: 150, height: 50))
            textlabel2.text = self.title[indexPath.section]
            textlabel2.numberOfLines = 0
            textlabel2.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            cell?.contentView.addSubview(textlabel2)

        }

      return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200.00
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){

    view.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "    "
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
  }

}
```

**GameScene:**

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var gameTableView = GameRoomTableView()
private var label : SKLabelNode?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    gameTableView.frame = CGRect(x:14,y:100, width: frame.maxX / 1.08, height: frame.maxY) //(scene?.view?.frame.maxY)!)
    gameTableView.contentSize = CGSize(width: gameTableView.frame.size.width, height: gameTableView.frame.size.height)

    self.scene?.view?.addSubview(gameTableView)
    gameTableView.reloadData()

    }
  }
```

the only problem I have is when I scroll to the bottom of the tableview It seems that half of the last cell is cut off from being scrolled to and I can’t see it fully the tableview has multiple sections because I wanted gaps between each cell and that was the only way I could achieve It. How do I change the scrolling of the tableview to be longer so I can see all of the cells fully? I have tried looking into other answers on here and I've had no luck fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the line:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        gameTableView.frame = CGRect(x:14,y:100, width: frame.maxX / 1.08, height: frame.maxY)
        ...
```

This happened because your `gameTableView` height is bigger than the scene height:

[image]

To solve you can try to decrease the height of your table for example:

```
gameTableView.frame = CGRect(x:14,y:100, width: frame.maxX / 1.08, height: frame.maxY/2)
```

Comment: is there another way to do it because i'm wanting to have a small space at the end of the tableview? because i also want the last cell at the end before the tableview is scrolled to the bottom to look like its going off the screen unless there is a way to add a uilabel to an skspritenode i need to get this effect but also have the small space at the end of the tableview

Comment: does that make any sense i can post a picture of what i'm trying to achieve if you want?